# Can't access Apple Developer Provisioning Portal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I  have an iphone application which i needed to be tested in the phone.My client created an account in the dev center and when i am login to this through the credentials it is showing access denied.can anybody knows how this is happening and also how to sort out this?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/overview/index.action

It will describe all for you?

Comment: there i am getting the access denied message

Comment: Where you getting Access denied message ?

Comment: Login via member center by using Company id and password then Only You can Access it.

Comment: If your getting it when you are logging in, it is possible that they have not activated the account by clicking on the link sent to them on an email. Unless you have already been into the account, then they could have done something that goes against Apple rules. This is only a guess.